# Which logger for Rails that gives Controller Name, Service Name

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Currently I'm getting this in my log files.

```
[42ba6cd6-f648-4f69-9a0b-999c3d410bd0] Adding a new account
```

I want it to include the caller.

```
[42ba6cd6-f648-4f69-9a0b-999c3d410bd0] [module=Api::AccountService] Adding a new account
```

My service looks like the following

```
module Api::AccountService

    include Logging
    def add
       logger.info "Adding a new account"
       # do something
       logger.info "Finished adding a new account"
    end
end
```

I'm using Lograge for my Rails app. Following is my config.

```
  config.lograge.enabled = true
  #config.colorize_logging = false
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]
  config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::KeyValue.new
```

My Logging module is as follows.

```
module Logging
    class << self
        def logger
            @logger ||= Rails.logger
        end

        def logger=(logger)
            @logger = logger
        end
    end

    # Addition
    def self.included(base)
        class << base
            def logger
                Logging.logger
            end
        end
    end

    def logger
        Logging.logger
    end
end
```

Comment: How about [`logging` library](https://github.com/TwP/logging/)?

Comment: I haven't tried it at all. Did you use it before? What is the difference?

Comment: FWIW, I wrote about [my discoveries of logging in Rails](https://medium.com/@Al_un/logging-on-rails-5-hide-and-seek-with-formatting-readibility-and-parsing-1c2014411540) By default, `logging-rails` create a logger for each class. Please have a look at the logging section to see some screenshots